# How to centering button in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, button, react-native, alignment

I am new to React Native currently learning about the technology.

I start create a simple layout with buttons inside it.

But my buttons aligned to left, how can I make it to the center ?

I've tried to `alignItems: 'center` and `justifyContent: 'center`

but it doesn't work.

I hope someone can help me so I can move on to another component

my buttons look like this:

[image]

Here some of my code:

```js
<Container>
                <View style={styles.tabContent}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>Engineering</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Inquiries Need Action</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                    <Button bordered dark style={styles.buttonTop}>
                        <View style={styles.buttonText}>
                            <Text>10</Text>
                            <Text>Dark</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.buttonIcon}>
                            <Icon name='ios-construct-outline' style={styles.icons}/>
                        </View>
                    </Button>
                    <Button bordered dark style={styles.button}>
                        <View style={styles.buttonText}>
                            <Text>10</Text>
                            <Text>Dark</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.buttonIcon}>
                            <Icon name='ios-construct-outline' style={styles.icons}/>
                        </View>
                    </Button>
                    <Button bordered dark style={styles.button}>
                        <View style={styles.buttonText}>
                            <Text>10</Text>
                            <Text>Dark</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.buttonIcon}>
                            <Icon name='ios-construct-outline' style={styles.icons}/>
                        </View>
                    </Button>
                    <Button bordered dark style={styles.buttonView}>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>VIEW ALL</Text>
                        </View>
                    </Button>
                </View>
            </Container>
```

this is the styling:

```css
buttonsContainer:{
        backgroundColor: '#7f8c8d',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonTop:{
        marginTop: 20,
        width: 250,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    button:{
        marginTop: 5,
        width: 250,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonView:{
        marginTop: 15,
        width: 250,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    },
    buttonIcon:{
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    },
    tabContent:{
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    },
    buttonText:{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        width: 100
    },
    text:{
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    title:{
        marginTop: 20,
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    subtitle:{
        color: '#7f8c8d',
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 15,
    }
```

Comment: Ok just to get this out of the way have you tried giving your button a style of alignSelf: 'center'

Comment: @NemiShah thanks you so much !!!!! :D you save me..I wish you have a good day :)

Comment: Happy to help and just in case
[More on Layout Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html)

Comment: Just a FYI, the style layouts you used were fine, but they only modified the children. In your case, another solution is to apply those styles to the parent container. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

make a  wrapper view above buttonContainer and give it style={{flex: 1}}

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
  <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
  ....
 </View>
</View>
```

`alignItems` and `justifyContent` are flex properties applicable when you define flex in parent container